# Can traits have secondary constructors in Scala 3?

Tags: scala, scala-3

I copied the following code form the [Auxiliary Class Constructors](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/scala-book/classes-aux-constructors.html) article, pasted into Scastie, changed `class` to `trait` and set the Scala version to 3.1.0:

```
val DefaultCrustSize = 12
val DefaultCrustType = "THIN"

// the primary constructor
trait Pizza (var crustSize: Int, var crustType: String) {

    // one-arg auxiliary constructor
    def this(crustSize: Int) = {
        this(crustSize, DefaultCrustType)
    }

    // one-arg auxiliary constructor
    def this(crustType: String) = {
        this(DefaultCrustSize, crustType)
    }

    // zero-arg auxiliary constructor
    def this() = {
        this(DefaultCrustSize, DefaultCrustType)
    }

    override def toString = s"A $crustSize inch pizza with a $crustType crust"

}
```

[Here's the result.](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/Tky5IWQoSiiVoxe6CPWqsw) It gives the following error:

```
org.scalameta.invariants.InvariantFailedException: invariant failed:
when verifying scala.meta.classifiers.`package`.XtensionClassifiable[scala.meta.Template](templ)(scala.meta.Tree.classifiable[scala.meta.Template]).is[Template.Quasi](Template.this.Quasi.ClassifierClass[scala.meta.Template]).||(templ.stats.forall(((x$9: scala.meta.Stat) => scala.meta.classifiers.`package`.XtensionClassifiable[scala.meta.Stat](x$9)(scala.meta.Tree.classifiable[scala.meta.Stat]).is[Ctor](scala.meta.Ctor.ClassifierClass[scala.meta.Stat]).`unary_!`)))
found that scala.meta.classifiers.`package`.XtensionClassifiable[scala.meta.Template](templ)(scala.meta.Tree.classifiable[scala.meta.Template]).is[Template.Quasi](Template.this.Quasi.ClassifierClass[scala.meta.Template]) is false
and also templ.stats.forall(((x$9: scala.meta.Stat) => scala.meta.classifiers.`package`.XtensionClassifiable[scala.meta.Stat](x$9)(scala.meta.Tree.classifiable[scala.meta.Stat]).is[Ctor](scala.meta.Ctor.ClassifierClass[scala.meta.Stat]).`unary_!`)) is false
where Template = scala.meta.Template$@7759c8f1
where templ = {

    // one-arg auxiliary constructor
    def this(crustSize: Int) = {
        this(crustSize, DefaultCrustType)
    }

    // one-arg auxiliary constructor
    def this(crustType: String) = {
        this(DefaultCrustSize, crustType)
    }

    // zero-arg auxiliary constructor
    def this() = {
        this(DefaultCrustSize, DefaultCrustType)
    }

    override def toString = s"A $crustSize inch pizza with a $crustType crust"

}
    at org.scalameta.invariants.InvariantFailedException$.raise(Exceptions.scala:19)
    at scala.meta.Defn$Trait$.internal$247(Trees.scala:432)
    at scala.meta.Defn$Trait$.apply(Trees.scala:425)
    at scala.meta.internal.parsers.ScalametaParser.$anonfun$traitDef$1(ScalametaParser.scala:4592)
    at scala.meta.internal.parsers.ScalametaParser.atPos(ScalametaParser.scala:888)
    at scala.meta.internal.parsers.ScalametaParser.traitDef(ScalametaParser.scala:4570)
    at scala.meta.internal.parsers.ScalametaParser.tmplDef(ScalametaParser.scala:4548)
    at scala.meta.internal.parsers.ScalametaParser.defOrDclOrSecondaryCtor(ScalametaParser.scala:4201)
    at scala.meta.internal.parsers.ScalametaParser.nonLocalDefOrDcl(ScalametaParser.scala:4172)
    at scala.meta.internal.parsers.ScalametaParser$$anonfun$templateStat$1$1.applyOrElse(ScalametaParser.scala:5120)
    at scala.meta.internal.parsers.ScalametaParser$$anonfun$templateStat$1$1.applyOrElse(ScalametaParser.scala:5114)
    at scala.runtime.AbstractPartialFunction.apply(AbstractPartialFunction.scala:35)
    at scala.meta.internal.parsers.ScalametaParser.statSeq(ScalametaParser.scala:5057)
    at scala.meta.internal.parsers.ScalametaParser.templateStats(ScalametaParser.scala:5130)
    at scala.meta.internal.parsers.ScalametaParser.templateStatSeq(ScalametaParser.scala:5110)
    at scala.meta.internal.parsers.ScalametaParser.$anonfun$templateBody$1(ScalametaParser.scala:4945)
    at scala.meta.internal.parsers.ScalametaParser.inBraces(ScalametaParser.scala:800)
    at scala.meta.internal.parsers.ScalametaParser.templateBody(ScalametaParser.scala:4945)
    at scala.meta.internal.parsers.ScalametaParser.templateBodyOpt(ScalametaParser.scala:4953)
    at scala.meta.internal.parsers.ScalametaParser.template(ScalametaParser.scala:4887)
    at scala.meta.internal.parsers.ScalametaParser.$anonfun$template$1(ScalametaParser.scala:4906)
    at scala.meta.internal.parsers.ScalametaParser.atPos(ScalametaParser.scala:888)
    at scala.meta.internal.parsers.ScalametaParser.autoPos(ScalametaParser.scala:922)
    at scala.meta.internal.parsers.ScalametaParser.template(ScalametaParser.scala:4891)
    at scala.meta.internal.parsers.ScalametaParser.$anonfun$templateOpt$1(ScalametaParser.scala:4931)
    at scala.meta.internal.parsers.ScalametaParser.atPos(ScalametaParser.scala:888)
    at scala.meta.internal.parsers.ScalametaParser.autoPos(ScalametaParser.scala:922)
    at scala.meta.internal.parsers.ScalametaParser.templateOpt(ScalametaParser.scala:4923)
    at scala.meta.internal.parsers.ScalametaParser.$anonfun$objectDef$1(ScalametaParser.scala:4682)
    at scala.meta.internal.parsers.ScalametaParser.atPos(ScalametaParser.scala:888)
    at scala.meta.internal.parsers.ScalametaParser.objectDef(ScalametaParser.scala:4674)
    at scala.meta.internal.parsers.ScalametaParser.tmplDef(ScalametaParser.scala:4558)
    at scala.meta.internal.parsers.ScalametaParser.topLevelTmplDef(ScalametaParser.scala:4540)
    at scala.meta.internal.parsers.ScalametaParser$$anonfun$topStat$1.applyOrElse(ScalametaParser.scala:5079)
    at scala.meta.internal.parsers.ScalametaParser$$anonfun$topStat$1.applyOrElse(ScalametaParser.scala:5067)
    at scala.runtime.AbstractPartialFunction.apply(AbstractPartialFunction.scala:35)
    at scala.meta.internal.parsers.ScalametaParser.statSeq(ScalametaParser.scala:5057)
    at scala.meta.internal.parsers.ScalametaParser.topStatSeq(ScalametaParser.scala:5066)
    at scala.meta.internal.parsers.ScalametaParser.$anonfun$batchSource$1(ScalametaParser.scala:5297)
    at scala.meta.internal.parsers.ScalametaParser.atPos(ScalametaParser.scala:888)
    at scala.meta.internal.parsers.ScalametaParser.autoPos(ScalametaParser.scala:922)
    at scala.meta.internal.parsers.ScalametaParser.batchSource(ScalametaParser.scala:5256)
    at scala.meta.internal.parsers.ScalametaParser.$anonfun$source$1(ScalametaParser.scala:5239)
    at scala.meta.internal.parsers.ScalametaParser.atPos(ScalametaParser.scala:888)
    at scala.meta.internal.parsers.ScalametaParser.autoPos(ScalametaParser.scala:922)
    at scala.meta.internal.parsers.ScalametaParser.source(ScalametaParser.scala:5238)
    at scala.meta.internal.parsers.ScalametaParser.entrypointSource(ScalametaParser.scala:5244)
    at scala.meta.internal.parsers.ScalametaParser.$anonfun$parseSource$2(ScalametaParser.scala:143)
    at scala.meta.internal.parsers.ScalametaParser.parseRule(ScalametaParser.scala:53)
    at scala.meta.internal.parsers.ScalametaParser.parseSource(ScalametaParser.scala:143)
    at scala.meta.parsers.Parse$.$anonfun$parseSource$1(Parse.scala:29)
    at scala.meta.internal.parsers.ScalametaParser$$anon$264.apply(ScalametaParser.scala:5308)
    at scala.meta.parsers.Api$XtensionParseDialectInput.parse(Api.scala:25)
    at scala.meta.parsers.Api$XtensionParseInputLike.parse(Api.scala:14)
    at com.olegych.scastie.instrumentation.Instrument$.apply(Instrument.scala:199)
    at com.olegych.scastie.instrumentation.InstrumentedInputs$.apply(InstrumentedInputs.scala:23)
    at com.olegych.scastie.sbt.SbtProcess$$anonfun$4.applyOrElse(SbtProcess.scala:191)
    at com.olegych.scastie.sbt.SbtProcess$$anonfun$4.applyOrElse(SbtProcess.scala:177)
    at scala.runtime.AbstractPartialFunction.apply(AbstractPartialFunction.scala:35)
    at akka.actor.FSM.processEvent(FSM.scala:707)
    at akka.actor.FSM.processEvent$(FSM.scala:704)
    at com.olegych.scastie.sbt.SbtProcess.processEvent(SbtProcess.scala:64)
    at akka.actor.FSM.akka$actor$FSM$$processMsg(FSM.scala:701)
    at akka.actor.FSM$$anonfun$receive$1.applyOrElse(FSM.scala:695)
    at akka.actor.Actor.aroundReceive(Actor.scala:539)
    at akka.actor.Actor.aroundReceive$(Actor.scala:537)
    at com.olegych.scastie.sbt.SbtProcess.aroundReceive(SbtProcess.scala:64)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.receiveMessage(ActorCell.scala:614)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:583)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:268)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:229)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.exec(Mailbox.scala:241)
    at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
    at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
    at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
    at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)
```

Why? And why is it after line 1, which seems perfectly fine and gets accepted when I remove the rest? Does "invariant failed" mean that it's a bug in the compiler? (Many other compilers in such cases add to the message an encouragement to report it.)

Main questions:

- Are secondary (or auxiliary – IIUC the two terms I've seen used apparently interchangeably mean the same) constructors allowed in traits?
- If so, how to call them?
- What are they useful for (or would be, or are in another language that actually has them)?

Comment: The compiler bug hypothesis gains probability. It's just occurred to me to turn off the worksheet mode. Now there are 3 errors saying "Traits cannot have secondary constructors", in the appropriate places. So it would seem my first two questions are answered. The one remaining: what secondary constructors of traits would be or are in another language useful for?

Comment: I went ahead with reporting: https://github.com/lampepfl/dotty/issues/14184.

Comment: I don't think it makes sense for a `trait` to have auxiliary constructors. Since it is abstract, those can't be called. And when extending it you must call the primary constructor. - In any case, in all my years using **Scala** I have never used, nor seen anyone use, a secondary constructor. Usually, is better to have axillary factories in the companion object.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez, why is it better?

And as for the philosophical unsoundness of secondary constructors in traits, Martin Odersky commented following my comment that it's about initialization order: https://github.com/lampepfl/dotty/issues/640#issuecomment-1002599628. Makes sense.

Comment: _"why is it better?"_ - 1. You can give the auxiliary factories proper names instead of overloading `new` or `apply` - 2. The factories can do validations and another kind of more complex logic that shouldn't be done in a constructor - 3. The factories may return the types wrapped in an `Option`, `Either`, `IO`, etc; if appropriate - 4. That would keep the class body cleaner and the logic of the factories may be extracted / abstracted to a trait; if required - 5. We rarely type `new` nowadays, which is another minor reason for preferring a factory than an auxiliary constructor.

Comment: So many good reasons – kudos! Any arguments for the other side, i.e. when secondary constructors may be preferred? And as for `new`, IIUC in Scala 3 it's completely unnecessary – everything works the same if it's omitted.

Comment: Yeah in **Scala 3** you don't need `new` because the compiler creates an artificial companion object with an artificial `apply` method for all classes, so if you please the mere existence of **Scala 3** is an argument in favor of factories over auxiliary constructors. - Anyways, no I don't have any argument in favor of secondary constructors they are just more limited and weirder than factories.

Comment: I think I've come up with a use case for auxiliary constructors: inheritance. When instantiating a derived class, a constructor of the base class must be called. If multiple are provided, the author of the derived class has a choice.

Comment: Well, I don't do inheritance so no idea really. AFAIK you have to call the main constructor but maybe no, so another thing to make inheritance even more complicated; so you have just gave me another reason for never having auxiliary constructors.

Comment: Every auxiliary constructor must call either the primary or one of the preceding secondary constructors. So the primary constructor always gets called eventually, unless there's an exception.

Comment: Another difference is that an abstract class can be a case class (the syntax is `abstract case class`), but there are no case traits.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[The documentation on `trait` parameters](https://docs.scala-lang.org/scala3/reference/other-new-features/trait-parameters.html) only mentions `trait` parameters, not `trait` constructors:

> Scala 3 allows traits to have parameters, just like classes have parameters.

It also links to the original SIP document for reference:

> For more information, see [Scala SIP 25](http://docs.scala-lang.org/sips/pending/trait-parameters.html).

In the *SIP-25 – `trait` parameters*, it says [**bold** emphasis mine]:

> In the `ClassDef` of traits, we still **do not allow secondary constructors**.

However, this restriction, is not reflected in the [*Syntax Summary*](https://docs.scala-lang.org/scala3/reference/syntax.html#declarations-and-definitions), which does not actually distinguish between `class`es and `trait`s syntactically. So, the restriction is purely one of documentation, not syntax specification.

So, to answer your question:

> Why?

Because your code is syntactically valid but semantically invalid, and ScalaMeta seems to not expect this specific kind of semantic invalidity.

> And why is it after line 1, which seems perfectly fine and gets accepted when I remove the rest? Does "invariant failed" mean that it's a bug in the compiler? (Many other compilers in such cases add to the message an encouragement to report it.)

It's clearly not a bug in the compiler since the exception is not thrown in the compiler, it is thrown in ScalaMeta.

> Main questions:
>
> - Are secondary (or auxiliary – IIUC the two terms I've seen used apparently interchangeably mean the same) constructors allowed in traits?

No. SIP-25 clearly disallows them.